# Bootstrap datepicker set date manually not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a legacy web app that is using some old version of bootstrap datepicker.  I've uploaded the entire datepicker.js file here. https://pastebin.com/aYzMrWgW

I am trying to set my Start Date picker up so that when it changes, I get the value selected and calculate the last day of the same month chosen, and set that value as the value for End Date.

I am using the code below to get the value from the Start Date picker `$('#dp1')` and attempting to set it to the value of the End Date picker `$('#dp1a')`.  When I check the console, my `lastDay` variable is correct.  If I choose 8/1/2017 - it logs out the string representation of 8/31/2017 and son on.  However I can not get it to update the End Date with the correct value.

```
$('#dp1').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
  $('.datePickerStart').change();
});

$('.datePickerStart').change(function() {
  // Parse the date and get the last day of the month selected
  var date = new Date($(this).val());
  var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 2, 0);
  console.log(lastDay);


  $('#dp1a').datepicker('setValue', lastDay);
});
```

If I call setValue as I am above, it sets the value to 9/1/2017 instead.

can anyone point out what i'm doing wrong please?

Comment: How about `$('#dp1a').datepicker('setValue', lastDay.split('/').reverse().join('-'));`

Comment: .split is not a function error in console.  lastDay is a Date object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your bootstrap datepicker version is too old and it doesn't seems to have the complete method `.datepicker('setValue', value)`.There are some line of code missing when compared to current version.You can check difference [here](https://www.diffchecker.com/PqQopzm6).
Even though i have made some changes in your code to setValue using your version.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var second = $('#dp1a').datepicker().data('datepicker');
$('#dp1').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
  $('.datePickerStart').change();
});

$('.datePickerStart').change(function() {
  // Parse the date and get the last day of the month selected
  var date = new Date($(this).val());
  var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 2, 0);
  console.log(lastDay);
  second.date=lastDay;
    second.setValue();
});
});
```

[old version fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nz4vjohq/)

But your code works perfect when updated with current version.Its always better to work with latest versions to avail these methods easily.

[current version fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agmxtzcd/)

Hope this helps!